# Loop though columns and print tables using survey weights from survey package

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to loop though columns of a dataset and create proportion tables. The survey package requires a '~' before variables making it tricky to loop through columns.

Data and design:

```
library(survey)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), weight=c(0,2,0.1), var1=c(2,3,5), var2=c(2,6,7))
design <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~weight, data=dat)
```

Attempt:

```
cols <- c("var1", "var2") # columns to loop through
for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
prop.table(svytable(~i, design))
}
```

I get the following error message:

`Error in model.frame.default(formula = weights ~ i, data = model.frame(design)) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'i')`

Thank you

Comment: Try building the formula from the column name - see if this works: `lapply(cols, function(x) prop.table(svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(x))), design)))`

Comment: `for( i in c('var1','var2'))print(prop.table(svytable(as.formula(paste("~",i)),design)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acknowledging the use of `bquote` as a partial substitution in expression from Ben's comment above, you could modify your `for loop` as follows:

```r
cols <- c("var1", "var2") # columns to loop through
for(i in  seq_along(cols)){
  print(prop.table(svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(cols[i]))), design)))
} 
# var1
#          2          3          5 
# 0.00000000 0.95238095 0.04761905 
# var2
#          2          6          7 
# 0.00000000 0.95238095 0.04761905
```

## Data

```r
library(survey)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), weight=c(0,2,0.1), var1=c(2,3,5), var2=c(2,6,7))
design <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~weight, data=dat)
```

Comment: How would I save this output into a df?